# I can´t find right values querying nested arrays with mongodb, mongoose and nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Dear stackoverflow community,

I usually no make posts here, but in this time i ask myself why not?, after 2 hours without getting a solution.

This one is pretty basic but involves a specific json model, mongoose, mongodb and nodejs.

Now the problem, is that i´m trying to get the data for the user_ppal_id : 1 and the exam_design_id : 1 , the search of the user_ppal_id succeeded, but the exam_design_id that is into a nested array always returns to me the value 1 and 2 (and i´m passing by parameter the exam_design_id 1)...

**This is my model**, **My nodejs rest method and how i´m using mongoose, nodejs and mongodb**, **My moongose model**, **A better view of the model from Umongo Ide:**

[SEE THE IMAGE HERE BECAUSE I AM NEW IN STACKOVERFLOW](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q3wxL.png)

All the structure is working, but the data from result is not the one i expected. You can check the response of this rest service by just clicking this url: http://207.244.75.230:8000/dyntestreports/getExamReport?idUserPpal=1&idExamDesign=1

In the response i´m getting the exam_design_id data for values 1 and 2 when i pass just the value 1.

Actually i tried with the following mongo queries and i not succeed:

1) ExamReportByUser.find({'user_ppal_id':userPpalId,'exams_created': {$elemMatch:{'exam_design_id': {$eq:examDesignId}}}}

2)ExamReportByUser.find({'user_ppal_id':userPpalId,'exams_created.0.exam_design_id':examDesignId}

At this moment i don´t know what i´m doing wrong even from a mongo console query i can´t get it works for just exam_design_id = 1 data.

I´m sure it could be a simple error but i´m not seeing it at this moment.

I really hope you can help me guys. Thanks in advance! Have a nice day.

Comment: Found it, but i wait for comments! My answer is below... Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

My bad! I just have found the solution... And i post it here for anyone that had the same doubt... The code querying the data should be like this (it was just keys syntax, basic mongo):

ExamReportByUser.find(**{'user_ppal_id':userPpalId},{'exams_created': {$elemMatch:{'exam_design_id': examDesignId}}}**,'id user_ppal_id exams_created exam_design_id user_submitted_exam',function(err, result) { if (err) return console.log(err); return res.send(result); }); };

Now i´m getting the data of user 1 and exam_design 1.

I will not select this as an answer, waiting for the specialists ;)